# How to delete an element which does not have a certain parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete list items who do not have a parent of `ul`

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="yamm-content">
    <div class="row">
        <li> <a href="#">Should be deleted</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Should be deleted</a>

        </li>
        <ul id="randomid" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <li> <a href="#">menu item</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">menu item</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">menu item</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="randomid2" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <li> <a href="#">menu item</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">menu item</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">menu item</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my current script:

```
if (!$('.nav .yamm-content row li').closest('ul').length == 0) {
    $(this).remove();
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/46NdQ/1/)

The first two list items don't have `ul`'s as parents. So they should be deleted.

Comment: Your HTML will not validate... I wonder ho's idea was to put `<li>` without a `<ul>` parent? How that happened?

Comment: shouldn't that be `.row`?

Comment: yes that should - didn't even see thanks, @RokoC.Buljan it's a cms, It's forcing my hand here

Answer (score 13):

Simple: `$('li:not(ul > li)').remove();`

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/46NdQ/3/

Comment: Your code does what the OP asked for, but shouldn't the OP actually remove any LI who's direct parent (not just any parent) isn't a UL since an LI is only valid HTML if it has a direct parent of UL, OL or MENU.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('li').filter(function(){return !$(this).closest('ul').length}).remove();
```

Or

```
$('li').not($('ul li')).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i used Javascript only and it may take some lines of coding. I suggest this may be useful some times when you don't want to go for jquery.

```
var len = document.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
for (var i=0;i<len;i++)
{
if (document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].parentNode.nodeName != "UL")
{ 
 document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].remove();
 i--;
}
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/f5K7j/)